# What do the abbreviations on this Jeppesen Dataplan mean?

Tags: flight-planning, commercial-operations

Attached is a screenshot from a flightplan created with Jetplan. Can someone help with decoding the format? What do the abbreviations mean in the table header?
[image: Jeppesen FlightPlan]
[image: page 2]

I understand the following:

FLT = Flight Level *100

T = ?

WIND = Wind speed & direction

TAS = True Air Speed

S = ?

GRS = ?

MCS = ?

DST = Distance to next waypoint

DSTR = Distance remaining

ETE = estimated time en-route

ETR = estimated time remaining

FU = fuel used?

FR = fuel remaining?

FF/E = ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GRS = Groundspeed

MCS = Magnetic Course

FU = Fuel burned that leg (100s)

FR = Fuel Remaining

T = OAT in degrees C, apparently without the sign.

S = Shear value (measure of turbulence) forecast

FF/E = Fuel Flow per Engine per hour

With thanks to @mins for filling in the gaps!

Comment: I doubt T is temperature. Is too high at those altitudes, even if it was in Fahrenheit.

Comment: @Stefan  Standard temp at FL180 is -21C, so 25 as temperature without the sign might be right.  This flightplan doesn't look to be in the stratosphere, just at 180.  The "S" value seems to always be a 1, unless it's omitted. No guess there.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, thank you to both @RalphJ and @mins!